# Python3.7 with Numpy on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, python-3

Goal:

Install Python3.7 on the Raspberry Pi. Then install Numpy for Python3.7

Found this very useful Github Gist: https://gist.github.com/SeppPenner/6a5a30ebc8f79936fa136c524417761d

Ran the following code in the console on the Pi(took ~1hour):

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev -y
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.0
./configure
make -j 4
sudo make altinstall
cd ..
sudo rm -r Python-3.7.0
rm Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
sudo apt-get --purge remove build-essential tk-dev -y
sudo apt-get --purge remove libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev -y
sudo apt-get --purge remove libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev -y
sudo apt-get --purge remove libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get clean
```

I then upgraded pip:

```
sudo python3.7 -m pi installl --upgrade pip
```

and finally installed Numpy for Python3.7 using pip:

```
sudo python3.7 -m pip install numpy
```

When trying to import numpy into python3.7 I got the (first) ImportError:

```
>>>import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
     from . import multiarray
   File "/user/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py" line 12, in <module>
     from . import overrides
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
     from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did install libf77blas.so.3 by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

But upon importing numpy I got another import error, this time numpy can't find `/lib/arm-linux/gnuabihf/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.27'`

I was not able to find a way to install GLIBC_2.27

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was surprisingly simple:

Install an older Numpy version - I went with:

```
sudo python3.7 -m pip install 'numpy>1.0, <1.15' --force-reinstall
```

The installation took looong, but I'm now able to import numpy in python3.7

Hope this helps someone..I spent way too much time figuring this out

Comment: Its works. I was stuck around 48 hours to install NumPy on raspberry pi 3B+ python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

`GLIBC_2.27` is not a library, it means that a symbol from `libc` with version `2.27` (or higher) is needed. You can try to install the `glibc` from the same repository where you got the `libatlas-base-dev`, they should have a compatible version. `libm` is part or `glibc`.

Newer versions of `glibc` should be upward compatible with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also force numpy to compile from source rather than using wheels that will have some minimum GLIBC from their compilation by doing

`pip install --no-binary numpy numpy`

(the doubling of numpy is like "pip install numpy, and install numpy from source")

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install numpy --global-option="-mfloat-abi=hard" --force-reinstall
```

...was the only answer that worked for me . The explanation is given in a thread on a slightly different problem see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161063/is-numpy-optimized-for-raspberry-pi-automatically/52415084#52415084)